# Take values from row and column of numpy array based on another array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a np array of weights

```
mat = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])
```

I have another numpy array containing the row and index to extract from the weight matrix.

```
row_col = np.array([
    [1, 1], # row 1, col 1
    [2, 2], # row 2, col 2
    [0, 2], # row 0, col 2
    [1, 0]  # row 1, col 0
])
```

How do I get the output:

```
[5, 9, 3, 4]
```

Comment: did you try `mat[row_col]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mat[row_col[:, 0], row_col[:, 1]]
```

Output: `array([5, 9, 3, 4])`